# Docker React-Native doesn't recognize android emulator

Tags: reactjs, docker, react-native, android-emulator, dockerfile

i'm building a "docker" for a "react-native" project (yes, i hear that's bad idea). I'm using this "docker" image:

[Dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/egewarth/a89663c583a13f6f22cf7e5436f287ce)

Before run docker I run android studio emulator via command line:
`./emulator @my_emulator`

I use `docker build -t react-native .` inside my react-native project to build the docker. To run docker I use `./react-native-container.sh`. 
[react-native-container.sh](https://gist.github.com/egewarth/3b19b97e45b41623d99bdad133c8a360)

After this, already in container, I run `yarn` inside `node_modules/react-native/` file.
Then I run:
`adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
react-native start > react-start.log 2>&1 &
react-native run-android`

Then I get the following error: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVMUw.png)

How can I make docker recognize android emulator?

Docker image based on [MaximeD](https://github.com/MaximeD/docker-react-native) image.

Comment: why not create an issue on the github page along with querying stackoverflow? also please paste that error in description, if you're posting an image you should embed it.

Comment: Is there any update, encountered issue got resolved or not?